# Unable to build the library using cargo lipo --release

Tags: ios, rust, rust-cargo

### Unable to build the library using cargo lipo --release

I am trying to make a cross-platform library using rust for ios target. I am following this article [(Building and Deploying a Rust library on iOS)](https://mozilla.github.io/firefox-browser-architecture/experiments/2017-09-06-rust-on-ios.html).
*Note: I followed the same steps and my project structure also looks the same *

After completing the code and project setup the last step is to build the library. When I try to build the library using `cargo lipo --release`. It throws this error:

`[ERROR cargo_lipo] No library target found for "my-project-name"`

Also, note that I am only able to **install support for two platforms**. (`aarch64-apple-ios` and `x86_64-apple-darwin`). I think the reason is that they have [dropped the support for 32-bit architectures](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/01/03/reducing-support-for-32-bit-apple-targets.html).

So, when I run
`rustup target add aarch64-apple-ios armv7-apple-ios armv7s-apple-ios x86_64-apple-ios i386-apple-ios`.

It throws error: `error: component 'rust-std' for target 'armv7-apple-ios' is unavailable for download for channel stable`

---

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "rustylib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
crate-type = ["staticlib", "cdylib"]
```

rustylib.rs

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *hello(const char *to);

void hello_release(char *s);
```

The rest of the project structure is the usual rust code.

#### The output of `rustup` show

Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/my-username/.rustup

### installed toolchains

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin

nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)

### installed targets for active toolchain

aarch64-apple-ios

x86_64-apple-darwin

### active toolchain

nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)

rustc 1.52.0-nightly (acca81892 2021-03-13)

### OS & Rust

Rust: rustc 1.50.0 (cb75ad5db 2021-02-10)

OS: macOS Bug Sur (11.2.3)

Xcode & Command line tools: 12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cargo.toml is wrong.

If you look into the guide you linked in your question, you can see, that the `crate-type` has to be below the `[lib]` tag like so:

```
[package]
name = "greetings"
version = "0.1.1"
authors = ["fluffyemily <fluffyemily@mozilla.com>"]
description = "Example static library project built for iOS"
publish = false

[lib]
name = "greetings"
crate-type = ["staticlib", "cdylib"]
```

Also your code has to be in `cargo/src/lib.rs` by default as stated in the document (and not in `rustylib.rs`).

You can run `cargo new rustylib --lib` from the command line to create all the boilerplate, so that you only have to add the dependencies and the `crate-type` in the `[lib]` section of your `Cargo.toml`.

### Edit

I think there is another problem:
You have entered C code in your `rustylib.rs` file, which can not work. I think what you intended to do, was to create the **C bridge**, which is called `cargo/src/greetings.h` in the guide you linked.

Comment: It was the toml. Seriously, never thought I'd make such a silly mistake. I was in such a hurry to get it running. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No Problem. Happens to all of us once in a while...